# need to create a Facebook tab for the mobile app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-page

I am having Google Play link(Android) and iTunes App Link(iTunes). I want to create a Facebook tab for my business page and on click of Facebook tab, my Google Play link can be opened.

I have registered myself on [developers.facebook.com/apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and created a new App. Now Under **Basic Info** I get confused on what to enter the value for **App Domains** so I have entered **play.google.com** because my Google Play link starts with this.

Now under **Page Tab**, I have entered all the required information but entered probably the wrong value for **Page Tab Edit URL** . So I finally save my application but it is not working.

So now I have deleted my **Page Tab** section and I then switched over to **App on Facebook** section where under **Canvas URL** I have placed my **Google Play** URL with all the required details and then submitted for review.

Before I submit for the review finally it asked me that there should be no external URL used But I have used my **Google Play URL** in the  **Canvas URL** section which is external.

I am completely confused now with this Facebook. I have also Googled a lot but with no result for me.

Please Guide me on integrating Android link(play.google.com) as Facebook Business Page tab.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using static iframe facebook application

What I did is simply created my desire page in HTML and placed it on my server and by static iframe facebook App, I called this page into IFrame.

Problem solved !